# dot product or distance of vectors after multiplying by orthonormal matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^k$ and $U \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times m}$ such that $m \le k$ and $U$ is orthonormal, i.e. $U^{\top}U = I$.

It is clear to me that $||U^{\top}x - U^{\top}y||_2$ can be bounded from above and below as some function of $U$ and $||x - y||$ (other than the simply inequality $||U^{\top} x - U^{\top} y|| \le ||U||\cdot||x-y|| \le ||x-y||$ which I think should be true).

Similarly, I get the sense I can bound $\langle U^{\top}x, U^{\top}y \rangle / (||U^{\top}x||\cdot||U^{\top} y||)$ from below and above as a function of $\langle x, y \rangle / (||x||\cdot||y||)$ or at least just the dot product (without the division by norms).

I want a sandwich for the distance or dot product of the projected vectors as a function of the original distance and dot product and $U$. What can I have?

EDIT: I realized I can follow all of this if I had some way, for a vector $z$, bounding from below and above $||U^{\top}z||$ by a function of $||z||$ and $U$ ($k$, $m$, etc.). Upper bound, I think is easy, the problem is lower bound.

CLARIFICATION based on comment below: $U$ doesn't have to be square, it could be that $m << k$. So, it could be $UU^{\top} \neq I$.

Comment: Orthogonal transformations are isometries so $\vert \vert Ux \vert \vert = \vert \vert x\vert \vert$. Use that $\langle x,y \rangle = x^Ty$ to prove this.

Comment: @CyclotomicField but $k$ can be larger than $m$. Not everything is preserved? For example, we could have a degenerate $U = e_1$.

Comment: For a semi-orthogonal matrix use that for orthonormal column vector $u$ the product $uu^T$ is the orthogonal projection onto the subspace spanned by $u$ and generalize to $UU^T$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField can you be a bit more specific for the lower bound?